# How to update only part of attributes, not all, in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an edit form for updating some attributes. But it tryes to edit all attributes, and cause of this I have validation error.

My form (edit view)

```
#person_info.fl_l
  - if @user.errors.any?
    .error_explanation
      %h2 Form is invalid
      %ul
        -for message in  @user.errors.full_messages
          %li= message


  =form_for @user do |f|
    %p
      Birthday:
      %br
      = f.date_select(:birthday,:start_year => 1940)
    %p
      Name:
      %br
      = f.text_field :name, :value=>@user.name
    %p
      Surname:
      %br
      = f.text_field :surname, :value=>@user.surname
    %p
      Nickname:
      %br
      = f.text_field :nickname, :value=>@user.surname       
    %p
      About Myself:
      %br
      = f.text_area :about_myself, :value=>@user.about_myself
    %p
      = f.submit "Update"
```

My update and edit actions:

```
def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

When I submit the form, it outputs validation errors like: "Password can't be blank"

So, how to update only part of attributes, not all? I dont want to update password in my case.

My user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :posts
  has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
  has_many :received_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "receiver_id"
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name, :presence => true,
            :length => {:maximum => 50}
  validates :email, :presence => true,
            :format => {:with => email_regex},
            :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}

  validates :password, :presence => true,
            :confirmation => true,
            :length => {:within => 6..40}


  before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }

  def send_password_reset
    generate_token(:password_reset_token)
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
  end

  def generate_token(column)
    begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
  end
end
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I have the exact same issue :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your model is invalid in its current state ... you're not sending in the password, so Rails is not touching that attribute.

In rails console, test:

```
user = User.find(whatever_the_id_is)
puts user.valid?
puts user.errors.inspect
```

My hypothesis is that it is invalid --- due to a missing password.

Comment: i added user model to question

Comment: yes , it's invalid, but how it can be? Because in my registration form works fine, and it have password input in it

Comment: If the model were created before you added password attributes, then it would be invalid but new models would be valid.

Comment: can you explain it more exactly, please

Comment: If you run a migration that adds "password" to a model, then existing models won't be valid anymore because they did not have a password at time of migration.

Answer (score 1):

Remove it from the params hash

```
params.delete(:password)
```

Or build your own hash to send to update.

Comment: i have added params.delete(:password) to update action, but it didnt work,  i have password presence validation , and it outputs me error

Comment: "Or build your own hash to send to update." i am newbie, donk know how to make it in my case(

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [Authentication in Rails 3.1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1) to smoothen out your authentication. it takes out a lot of code from your model.

Then, I noticed that: if a field is hidden from the form for any reason, rails does not pass this in the params hash for an update. So you can play with hiding fields in a form. This is how I solve mine.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by appending

```
,:on => :create
```

to my validates_presence_of and validates_length_of lines.

Comment: This is what you want if you don't want to pass in a password for updating the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this in the User password validation like so:

```
validates :password, :presence     => true,
                     :confirmation => true,
                     :if           => :password # only validate if password changed!
```

Comment: Whoops, just noticed this won't solve your problem if left alone like that, since you could end up updating your password without validation! I added an attr_accessible to password to make it only available on :create and :update_password. Just in case you're considering to go this way as well -- or maybe just combine my and @mb14's answer

Comment: " I added an attr_accessible to password to make it only available on :create and :update_password" can you explain how to do this, please?

Comment: combining your and mb14 answers doesnt output errors but it didnt save changes.

Comment: I meant rather than modifying the params one, just create a new one with everything but password in it.

Comment: i dont understand, i have added my user model, maybe , if you have some time, check it, maybe something wrong there